# Keep one view orientation when rotating

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I have the app with two view controllers.

The first view controller contains two subview: one would keep it's orientation; second - would be rotated (like camera layer and controls in iOS Camera app).
The second – should support all orientations. 
I've found a solution: to keep first view controller in Portrait mode and rotate the subview manually, by handling UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification. 
The problem is in iOS 6.0. 
I've tried to add category for UINavigationController, but it seems like rotation rules are global.

A sample code is attached
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2167984/temporary/rotationSample.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue: just moved first view controller out of navigation controller and show the second view controller as modal.